# How to Convert cursor of get_all() into Map or list map in Rethinkdb's java driver?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have problem to convert value from get_all(array) in string(as json) or Map.

```
 RqlCursor cursor = r.db("test").table("x").get_all(arraylist)
```

when I try to fetch like

```
for(RqlObject o : cursor) {
        if (o instanceof java.util.List<?>) {
            List<Object> list = o.getList();
          }else if (o instanceof ListIterator<?>) {
            List<Object> list = o.getList();
            array.add(list);
          }else {
              java.util.Map<String, Object> map = o.getMap();
            }
}
```

None of other instances than `Map` catches above condition and generated error `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map` 
How can I get this Object in map or array of list map or even in json formatted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got Answer myself from another source. first we have to check type with `.as` method. 
here is full code

```
for(RqlObject c : cursor) {
    Object o = c.as();     
    if (o instanceof java.util.List<?>) {
         List<Object> list = o.getList();
     }else if (o instanceof ListIterator<?>) {
         List<Object> list = o.getList();
     }else {
         java.util.Map<String, Object> map = o.getMap();
     }
}
```